# Display image data

Tags: c++, image-processing

I am trying to figure out how an image (mostly Tiff and jpg) can be visualized via C++. although, there exist some predefined libraries, I wish to work out on this my shell itself. Any hint or way to find c++ codes for this.

Note: Please, believe me, this is not a homework and I am struggling to do this as I am using some old version c++ library so that I can not link new libraries like opencv.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to make a good old text-only renderer to start understanding what an "image" really is.

Comment: Quite simply, you read the file-header, follow the directions/assertions made in it, before locating and decoding the data. There are multiple formats of each, employing a number of different image compression techniques. You would be _much_ better off (a) doing the .BMP or .TGA format first - they're both quite simple. (b) chucking the old libraries and getting new stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reason people use libraries for this stuff - it's hard. All but the simplest formats take a lot of code to decode.

For JPEG the standard is the [IJG group's](http://www.ijg.org/) implementation.

For TIFF you can use [LibTIFF](http://www.libtiff.org/).

Neither of these libraries is trivial.